# Save the body of an Exchange 2010 message to a file

Tags: email, exchange-2010, text

We are completing our upgrade from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010.  We created an event sink to write the body of email messages with specific Subject lines to a text file for automated processing.  Event sinks were discontinued in Exchange 2007.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the body of an email into a text file with Exchange 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're after are now [Transport Agents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012.aspx).

The SDK for Exchange 2010 SP1 (including samples) can be found on [this Microsoft download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=99989695-5116-4ec6-93c3-8395de84996d).

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking into the Edge Transport Logging example as a start to my solution.